# Does MySQL Connector/Net translate my inline SQL into code?

Tags: sql, ado.net, mysql-connector

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I don't know the answer.  If I use [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.1.html), when I send SQL via ADO.NET, does my inline SQL get translated into code first and then sent to the database, or does it get sent as SQL text, and then the database engine has to translate it into code?

Or doesn't ADO.NET do a translation?

Or, if my thinking about this seems way off, please set me straight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets sent as SQL and the database side is responsible for parsing and executing it.